# How to find an element in a vector?

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I have defined a structure Coord as

```
struct Coord { 
int x;
int y;
int z; 
};
```

Overloaded operator!= for Coord

```
bool Coord::operator !=(Coord& crd)const {
if(this->x != crd.x)
{
    if(this->y != crd.y)
    {
        if(this->z != crd.z)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    else
        return false;
    return true;
}
else
    return false;
}
```

Then initialized a vector variable as

```
vector<Coord> vcoord;
```

Now I am using following code to get index of vector having a perticular Coord object

```
int Index::getVIndex(Coord crd) { 
vector<Coord>::iterator it;
int indx;

it = vcoord.begin();
while(it != vcoord.end() && (*it) != crd)
    ++it;

indx = distance(vcoord.begin(),it);
cerr << (*it).x << " " << (*it).y << " " << indx << endl;
return indx;
}
```

But the value of indx is always 0. Kindly help to get correct result.

Comment: What values are you putting in `vcoord`, and what value are you passing to `getVIndex`? How is `operator!=` defined for `Coord`? Better still, can you post a small, complete program that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: ya it complied and executing, giving indx as 0 always.

Comment: The index is always zero because you never place any elements in to `vcoord`.

Comment: Mankarse : It is code snippet vcoord has been populated before calling this function

Comment: See Mike S comment above... post working code that reproduces the error. It will get you help quicker

Comment: Reinventing the wheel. Define `operator==`, then use `std::find`.

Answer (score 3):

<strike>You need a not-equals operator for your `Coord` struct in order to be able to do this:</strike>

```
(*it) != crd
```

The logic of your not-equals operator is incorrect.  The best and easiest option is to provide an equality comparison and use [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find):

```
struct Coord { 
int x;
int y;
int z; 
};

bool operator == (const Coord& lhs, const Coord& rhs)
{
  return lhs.x==rhs.x && lhs.y==rhs.y && lhs.z==rhs.z;
}
```

You can then implement `!=` in terms of `==`, but you don't need it if you use `std::find`, which uses `==` by default:

```
vector<Coord>::iterator it = std::find(vcoord.begin(), vcoord.end(), crd);
```

Comment: Did you give up because you got an error, that's what your comment implies?

Answer (score 2):

Your `!=` operator returns `true` only if *all* coordinates differ; it should return `true` if *any* differ. This means your function will return zero if any coordinate of the first element matches the function argument's.

Your version is a long-winded way of writing:

```
return x != crd.x && y != crd.y && z != crd.z;
```

when it should be:

```
return x != crd.x || y != crd.y || z != crd.z;
```

It may be easier to get the logic correct by implementing it in terms of `==`:

```
bool operator==(Coord const & lhs, Coord const & rhs) {
    return lhs.x == rhs.x && lhs.y == rhs.y && lhs.z == rhs.z;
}
bool operator!=(Coord const & lhs, Coord const & rhs) {
    return !(lhs == rhs);
}
```

Also, given a definition of `==`, you can use `std::find` rather than rolling your own loop:

```
auto found == std::find(vcoord.begin(), vcoord.end(), crd);
if (found == vcoord.end()) {
    // Decide what to do if not found.
    // Returning zero is a bad idea, since there's no way distinguish that 
    // from a successful outcome.
} else {
    return std::distance(vcoord.begin(), found);
}
```

Comment: Thanks all for pointing out my mistake and helping me out, now find is working fine and I am using the same.

Answer (score 1):

You incorrectly implemented the logic in the inequality operator.
It should be

```
bool Coord::operator !=(const Coord& crd)const {
  return x != crd.x || y != crd.y || z != crz.z;
}
```

Your implementation is logically equivalent to

```
  return x != crd.x && y != crd.y && z != crz.z;
```